# Simplifying the expression ${\frac{0.5-e^{-{\sqrt{2}}t}(\cos\sqrt{2} t + \sin \sqrt{2} t)}{-2 \sqrt{2}e^{-{\sqrt{2}}t}(\sin\sqrt[ ]{2}t)}}$

Tags: calculus

Sorry to bother, how can the next quotient be simplified?

$$
{\displaystyle \frac{0.5-e^{-{\sqrt{2}}t}(\cos\sqrt{2} t + \sin \sqrt{2} t)}{-2 \sqrt{2}e^{-{\sqrt{2}}t}(\sin\sqrt[ ]{2}t)}}
\
$$

I've been told that multipling by
$$
\displaystyle\frac{e^{{\sqrt[ ]{2}}t}}{e^{{\sqrt[ ]{2}}t}}
$$

That yields
$$
{\displaystyle \frac{0.5e^{{\sqrt{2}}t}-(\cos\sqrt{2}t+\sin\sqrt{2}t)}{-2 \sqrt{2}(\sin\sqrt{2}t)}}
\
$$
equal to
$$
\displaystyle\frac{0.5e^{{\sqrt{2}}t}}{2\sqrt{2}\sin\sqrt{2}t}-\displaystyle\frac{\cos\sqrt{2}t}{2\sqrt{2}\sin\sqrt{2}t}-\displaystyle\frac{\sin\sqrt{2}t}{2\sqrt{2}\sin\sqrt{2}t}
$$

could it be any reduction in the 
$$
\displaystyle\frac{0.5}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$
and the second term, could be writen as $\cot$ or $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\tan}$? Which is more suited to choose?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put $\sqrt2t=\theta$ then you have for the given expression  $E$,

$$E=\frac{1}{-2\sqrt2\sin \theta}\left(\frac{e^{\theta}}{2}+\cos \theta+\sin \theta\right)$$
But you have $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac 12=\sin\frac{\pi}{6}$ therefore
$$E=\frac{-\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\left(e^{\theta}\sin\frac{\pi}{6}+\cos\theta+\sin\theta\right)}{2\sin\theta}$$
You have now to apply with care the formulas
$$-2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\sin\frac{A-B}{2}=\cos A-\cos B\\2\cos\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}=\cos A+\cos B\\2\sin\frac{A+B}{2}\cos\frac{A-B}{2}=\sin A+\sin B$$
I give you a part of the calculations and it is your job  the other two similar ones and finally simplify what you get. You have
$$E=\color{red}{\frac{e^{\theta}}{\sin\theta}\left(\frac{\cos\frac{5\pi}{12}-\cos\frac{\pi}{12}}{4}\right)}+\frac{(-\sin\frac{\pi}{4})(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}{2\sin\theta}$$

Comment: Whoa! Interesting comment, isn't what I was expecting, thanks a lot!!

Comment: You are welcome.